# Indentation error with tab in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error, indentation

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdnZm.png)

[here is the resutlt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbo0n.png)

But when I did that, with by press "delete" button to backtab, I ran into an error
[indentation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfVwb.png)

Comment: Include the code and result directly on the post using code tags.

Comment: When you do; please paste the *full* error message. This only shows one line of the error message, which just says it’s a syntax error instead of an indentation error in particular.